# Many instances of an application scoped Seam component

Tags: java, seam

I have a Seam component annotated like this:

```
@AutoCreate
@Name("asyncServiceManager")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
public class AsyncServiceManager {
```

The classes that use it are configured like this:

```
@In("#{asyncServiceManager}")
private AsyncServiceManager asyncServiceManager;
```

When running the code, I see that the class `AsyncServiceManager` is instantiated everytime it is used. As I annotated the class with scope APPLICATION, this should not be the case. I need this class to be a singleton.

Comment: @raoulsson If possible, tell us what was happening. Have you solved your problem yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can simply your configuration.  You don't need this:

```
@In("#{asyncServiceManager}")
```

Instead, since your variable name is identical to the component name, this is sufficient

```
@In
private AsyncServiceManager asyncServiceManager;
```

Depending on how often your component is used (this is an optimization), you can make it an event-scoped component, have it auto-created when an event is observed, and then let it get destroyed after that.

Walter

Comment: @Walter White Hi Walter, do not forget when using @In without create attribute enabled, Seam does not create a Seam component if it does not exist. But when using a Expression Language (lookup with option to create) as used by Raul @In(#{asyncServiceManager}), Seam creates one if it does not exist. (+1) for naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Seam in Action book says:

> Any components marked as application-scoped startup components (i.e., annotated with both @Startup and @Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)) **are automatically instantiated by Seam at this time**.

So i think @AutoCreate annotation should be removed.

Seam uses SeamListener to bootstrap @Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION) marked components.

regards,